# Appium Program crash on isDisplayed

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to check the visibility of a hidden element in my UI. When the element is on the screen, isDisplayed returns true. Else, When the element is not visible on the screen and is hidden, my Program crashes on isDisplayed.

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("com.appiumdemoapp:id/btnInvisible")).isDisplayed());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing because the element cannot be found, so you need to pre-condition the assert by first checking to see if the element exists:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.id("com.appiumdemoapp:id/btnInvisible")).size() = 0)
 Assert.fail("Element not found");
else
 Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("com.appiumdemoapp:id/btnInvisible")).isDisplayed());
```

Comment: Since isDisplayed is a Boolean so how can it just hold only value ie true and never hold false. @BillHileman

Comment: It can be false, but only if the element exists in the document.  If it does not exist in the document, it's likely your locator is not correct.  The initial check is a fail safe to cover that very scenario.  If your test reports "Element not found" (and you can embellish that message, of course) then you know that you're either not on the page you think you are, or there's a problem with the locator.

Comment: to check this i added a button to the view which is hidden. it has a locator (I used id to locate it) In this scenario, its still returning an exception rather than false.Since the button is in the view but is hidden and may be it will be visible if some condition returns true how will i check for its visibilty when that condition is called? Is this possible with isDisplayed and will it return false in this situation because for me its returning an exception.

Comment: I don't know what to say except this might be a difference between Selenium and Appium.  It could be that in Appium, the element is not considered existing if it's not visible.  Based on your info, I would probably write my own version of isDisplayed that checks for the existence of the element instead of its visible property, or implement the code I used and return false if the element does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
boolean isVisible;
 try{
     MobileElement element=driver.findElementByXpath("Xpath");
     isVisible=element.isDisplayed();
    }catch(Exception e){
      isVisible=false;
    }
if(isVisible){
Assert.assertTrue(isVisible);}
else{
Assert.assertFalse(isVisible);
}
```